# PHP / Laravel - Sending array in JSON returns empty

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am trying to send multiple PDF files (ContentBytes) to my Laravel server, using JSON.

In POSTMAN, this is my request:

```
{
  "content:" ["ContentBytesOfFileOne", "ContentBytesOfFileTwo", 
  "ContentBytesOfFileThree"]
}
```

Now I am sending the actual bytes of the PDF file, so my content array is too large to post here.

In my Laravel controller, I try to access it like this:

```
 $content = $request->content;

 //Validate the request
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'content' => 'required|array'
 ]);

 dump($content);
```

The `dump($content)`returns `null`, but the `$validator` doesn't throw an error.

If I dump my `$request` variable, it returns this as the content:

```
#content: """
    {
        "content": ["JVBERi0xLjINCjEgMCBvYmogPDwgL1Byb2R1Y2VyIChQQ0wyUERGIGZyb20gVmlzdWFsIFNvZnR3YXJlKQ0KL1RpdGxlIChDb252ZXJ0ZWQgZnJvbSBkYXRhX1B1bHNlX0tvbGRpbmdcXHRtcFxccGRmMjBDOUQwOUZFMjUzMjgxNTQzMzk0NTgwNzQ3MS50bXApDQovQXV0aG9yIChOZWlsIEouIEdlZGRlcykNCi9DcmVhdG9yICgpD.......
```

See below screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: dump($content) will return null because you haven't set $content anywhere. If you dump($request->content); you'll see the content.